# Loop through <a> tag of a web page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I'm building a web crawler with Python using Selenium. This is the webpage I'm crawling data from:

- https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=11026627000138&idCategoriaDocumento=6&idTipoDocumento=45

As you can see, the table inside this page changes as we click on the buttons identified with number. The page is a Brazilian funds report. 'Anterior' means 'previous' and 'seguinte' means next. I want to iterate through all those numbers, but none of what I've tried is working. I'm trying to click on the `<a>` tag that identifies the `Seguinte` button with the `click()` method from Selenium.

#### What I tried

```
browser = Firefox()

button = browser.find_element_by_id('tblDocumentosEnviados_next')
while button.is_enabled(): 
               
    page = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "paginate_button current")]').text
    print(page)
    button = browser.find_element_by_id('tblDocumentosEnviados_next')
    time.sleep(3)
    button.click()
```

How can I iterate through those numbers?

Comment: Are you sure selenium is the correct tool for a webcrawler? It's fairly expensive to open a browser for this purpose.

Comment: @DMart, i have no idea, do you think its too expensive? plz share your thoughts

Answer (score 1):

As you see the difference between 2 buttons is just the number of

```
//*[@id="tblDocumentosEnviados_paginate"]/span/a[1]
//*[@id="tblDocumentosEnviados_paginate"]/span/a[2]
```

If you want to iterate through it you can simple change the number in the xpath

for example

```
 for i in range(1, numberOfPages):
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id="tblDocumentosEnviados_paginate"]/span/a["+str(i)+"]")
```

Hope this solves what you were trying to do

Answer (score 1):

I analyzed the requests made by the website and noticed you can get all the data with one request as json content:

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
url = "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=11026627000138&idCategoriaDocumento=6&idTipoDocumento=45"

res = r.get("http://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/pesquisarGerenciadorDocumentosDados?d=0&s=0&l=200&"+url.split("?")[1])
json_result = json.loads(res.text)
print(json_result)
```

Notice: if the "recordsTotal" exceeds 200, you need to make another request with the parameter "?d=0&s=200&l=200", s stands for start and l stand for limit, always keep it 200 to scrape the maximum in one request.

Answer (score -1):

After you did a click on Next button with `button.click()` DOM is refreshed and `button` becomes stale.

You need to update `button` on each iteration. Try below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = Firefox()

while True:
    try:
        button = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "tblDocumentosEnviados_next")))
        page = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class, "paginate_button current")]').text
        print(page)
        button.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```